# Buffer/Capture Oracle SQL querys on Application server

Tags: .net, windows, oracle11g, oraoledb

​Hi.

I have an old .Net application that every minute calls a stored procedure on a remote Oracle DB, with a set of variable parameters using the OraOLEDB provider.

**My problem is that if the network connection drops between the app server and the database, I lose my vital data.**

**Does anyone have an idea how I can prevent dataloss, if the connection from the Application Server to the Oracle Database is lost.**

I.e. capture/buffer the sql querys on the server and resend them once the connection is reestablished to the DB.

Additional info:

- I do not have access to change the source code of the .Net application.
- I have access to reconfigure the database connection string (OraOLEDB connection parameters) and anything in the DB.
- I have full access to the server and infrastructure.
- My application server runs Windows 2012 R2.
- The DB is Oracle 11g.
- The connection paramaters look like so:

Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MYDATABASE;User
   ID=MYUSER;Password=MYPASSWORD;PLSQLRSet=1;VCharNull=0;UseSessionFormat=TRUE

Answer (score 0):

This might be silly, but, i'd push into a local database small restricted database (depending on what hardware you have/licenses etc) , that i use as master to replicate to the one you using at the moment.